# jQuery mousemove: have navbar appear only when mouse moves

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I've figured out how to have a navbar appear on mousemove, but I'm have trouble figuring out how to have it disappear again after the mouse stops moving.

CSS

```
nav{
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {     
  $("nav").css("display", "block");
});
```

I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I've been looking for a while to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: How fast does it need to disappear? Immediately after it stops moving? Why not just make a `setTimeout` where after 2-3 seconds it automatically disappears. The webpage is constantly tracking whether or not the mouse is moving anyways so it won't disappear unless the user idles for more than however long you choose.

Comment: @aug I just posted a solution similar to what you suggest with a 50ms timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use a timeout system like this:

```
var timer;

$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
  $('nav').addClass('show');
  try {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  } catch (e) {}
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $('nav').removeClass('show');
  }, 50);
});
```

With styles like this:

```
nav {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The 50ms makes it adjustable to how sensitive you want it to be.

Comment: this works, thanks. now only to find a way for it to appear and disappear a bit more smoothly...

Comment: @user1912899 If you want it to be smoother I would create a class that has the visible state and use a CSS transition on it. Then just toggle that class. I don't think you can transition `display: none` to `display: block`, but `visibility: hidden` and `opacity` are viable options for that.

Comment: @user1912899 I've updated my answer to be a little easier on the user (transitionally). Left of vendor prefixes for brevity. [Fiddle Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/84FYN/)

Comment: that's great, thanks a lot. but what about .fadeIn() and .fadeOut()? wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: @user1912899 `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` would work, but you might have to call `.stop()` every time you faded in and out. The CSS just handles it nicely by default.

Answer (score 2):

You could register a mouse stop event on mouse move and remove the event after it has been called. Since you are using jQuery you can also use .show() and .hide() instead of changing the css directly. You can get a plugin for a mouse stop event [here](http://richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event)

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){     
    $("nav").show();
    $(document).mousestop(function(e) {
        $("nav").hide();
        $(document).unbind('mousestop');
    });
});
```

If you decide to you .show and .hide you should take a look at the api documentation. With a few extra params you can easily show and hide with a nice animation instead of an instant appear and disappear

[jQuery show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[jQuery hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native event in jQuery for the end of mousemove,
but you can use some of the various jQuery plugins for mousestop on the internet like

http://www.jquery4u.com/events/writing-mousestop-event-plugin-jquery/

Then, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){     
    $("nav").show();
});

$(document).mousestop(function(e) {
    $("nav").hide();
});
```